# Should one trust other developers while implementing an API?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, documentation

Let's assume you work on a (PHP, but it doesn't matter) library which would be used by other developers at some point. The library is well covered with unit tests to ensure that it works as expected, some edge cases are tested as well, like throwing an exception on obviously bad arguments (like passing an array where a scalar value is expected etc.). Should one write more unit tests and build more value checks into the code to ensure that an invalid value is never passed and an exception is thrown, while sacrificing performance or should one stop and document that a non-sense value is permitted, but shouldn't be passed?

E.g you code a URL class and you have the option to allow setting a host value which contains invalid characters or of a bad length etc. Should you allow it and hope that other developers will never pass a bad value or should you write checks and sacrifice performance in favor of integrity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only an opinion...I think you can't trust the API users unless you control both ends.
If you are not the only one who is going to use it, you need to make sure that only "OK values" will be passed the first layer of your API.
To prevent performance problems you can consider the opposite approach (if it works with the solution needs and implementation), instead of searching for all the wrong cases and inputs you can try to check if the value is ok, and if not throw an exception (i.e, the host value can be checked with a REGEX role to make sure it is the right pattern, otherwise exception will be thrown).

There are several criteria\questions that can help with that decision:

Who is going to use your service, now and in the future?  Consider scenarios like company expands or even purchased.

Who is going to be affected from a "bad input" case? Is it going to effects only the single operation that caused it or it might effects other future operations or even other users (e.g. leads to a system crash, insert non valid data to the database, files or global memory etc.).

Can you trust the one who is going to use your service and its data? Is he taking his data from another source that might be corrupted or just non-valid?

How much the validation checks costs? Is it expensive compering to the rest of the work that needs to be done (performance wise) and if so, can it be written more efficiently?

The answers to these questions can help to find the right solution for a specific scenario.
I usually go with the [Defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) approach.

Comment: This is how I've been doing it as well, whitelist checking for a value to be OK, exception otherwise. However, the check is rather time consuming and is an actual performance hit. It might be unnecessary at all if the other developers would stick to the OK values, but I can't guarantee it, hence the question.

Comment: I updated my answer so it will be more detailed

Comment: Thanks for the update, you are right with the defined criteria, the main point for me has been the data integrity part, since the absence of checks could possibly lead to corrupt/invalid data if it would be provided. So to make sure that the developer doesn't have to make the checks himself, which would be just as expensive, I rather build them into the library to make everyone happy.